# My Built Jar File not Working outside netbeans - NetBeans IDE 16

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, jar, jvm

When I need to run .jar java file after build it from netbeans , the file not opening !
but I am not sure if the problem from netbeans or java , because I have old jar files built with netbeans that used to work, but after updating java, they don't all work anymore!

I tried running the file indirectly via the .bat file: java -jar myapp.jar , but it didn't work either

Comment: ["Didn't work"](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/77-doesntwork)
doesn't help

Comment: Can you show us the log of your error?

Comment: I don't have log of this error , because the app is working well when i run the project from netbeans , but when i go to run it from jar file , the app doesn't open

Comment: Run the jar from the command line. Post any error message(s) *formatted as code*

Comment: Although there is a main file , the error : (no main manifest attribute, in ebadalrahmanalqareealmaher-1.0.jar)

Comment: You haven't built an *executable* jar properly

Comment: To augment the other comments, you can run your application by specifying the main class explicitly, `java -cp myapp.jar name.of.your.MainClass`. Or you update the jar file once, to become an executable jar, using `jar ufe myapp.jar name.of.your.MainClass`. After this, `java -jar myapp.jar` should also work.